# Average value of centripetal force in polar coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

**Problem description:** A car with mass m is moving with a constant speed $v$ in a quarter circle of radius $R$ in a time $t=\tau$. What is the magnitude of the average frictional force $\overline{F}$ acting on the car?

I can find it easily in rectangular coordinates as:

$$\overline{F} = 2\sqrt{2}\dfrac{mv^2}{\pi R}$$

Where I am confused is how this would be expressed in polar coordinates. However I look at it I can't seem to wrap my head around it even being possible. For example, through the impulse-momentum theorem one can express:

$$\Delta \vec{p}=\int_0^{\tau} \vec{F} dt$$

But, in polar coordinates, the change in momentum would be zero:

$$\Delta \vec{p} = mv \vec{e}_{\theta}-mv\vec{e}_{\theta} = \vec{0}$$

This feels natural in the sense that the force is zero in the $\theta$-direction. What does not make sense to me is how we would express the change in momentum in a radial direction when the momentum is always zero. Paradoxically, the force in the radial direction is nonzero so how does that work. Does it have something to do with the radial direction at $t=0$ being the angular direction at $t=\tau$?

I realize now that I'm confusing myself even by asking the question, I hope that someone can interpret what I mean.

Comment: Note that adding vectors in polar coordinates as you do in Cartesian coordinates is incorrect, as the unit vectors change direction with position. You should always do your work in Cartesian and then convert to polar at the end. Although here the question seems poor because what spatial position would you use for the average in polar coordinates?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Yes, I do not know. Maybe that is the problem; the question does not have an answer since it's ill-posed. 

The initial motivation iirc was that the centripetal force is constant in magnitude so "wouldn't it be easier just to say that the average frictional force is equal to the centripetal force?".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's define a cylindrical coordinate system $(r , \theta)$.

You probably must have derived that,

$$\vec{v}=r \frac{d\theta}{dt} \hat{\theta}$$

Now the thing to wrap your head around is that the body is just turning due to the centripetal force, there is a force in a radial direction but by the time it moves radially it goes forward and curves around and makes a circle.

As for your problem, we need the change in momentum's radial component:

$$\dot{\vec{p}}=mr \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} \hat{\mathbf{\theta}}+mr\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d \hat{\theta}}{dt}$$

Now let us just quickly convert this to cartesian and return back to polar:

$$\hat{\theta}(t)=-\sin \theta \hat{i}+\cos \theta \hat{j}$$

If we differentiate wrt t:

$$\frac{d\hat{\theta}(t)}{dt}=(-\cos \theta \hat{i}-\sin \theta \hat{j})\frac{d\theta}{dt}=-\hat{r} \frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

So I think you must have figured out how to represent the net force in polar coordinates:

$$\dot{\vec{p}}=mr \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} \hat{\mathbf{\theta}}-mr \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2 \hat{r}$$

Now, you can average the force by integrating over a desired interval and dividing by its length.

Comment: Thank you! I think you missed the inner derivative of the terms when you differentiated the angular component. It is corrected in the final step.

I worked through that representation earlier and found that I must convert to cartesian in the integral since the polar unit vectors change direction over time. I thought that it is then no longer "expressed in polar coordinates" but understand now where I thought wrong.

Comment: Yeah oops messed that eqn up but I hope everything else is fine